# Having error when trying to update bit value to "0" using left shift

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-or

I'm trying to change the value of x from 5 to 7 to 6 using these bitwise operators. However, the second time where it says `x = (x|(0 << 0));` yields no change and is ignored when I trace it.

No errors. Any tips?

```
int main() {
    unsigned short x = 5;
    
    x = (x|(1 << 1));
    printf("%hd\n", x);
    x = (x|(0 << 0));
    printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `0 << 0` is 0.  `x | 0` is `x`.  If you wish to _remove_ bit 0 you can mask it: `x &= ~1U`

Comment: and what is `0 << 0`?  I think you mean `1 << 0` in this case.  That won't give you a 6 though as 5 is binary 101.  You need to clear the low bit and set the 2nd lowest bit to do that.

Comment: No I don't mean that I want 0 << 0 because I want to replace the 0th bit like index 0 with the value 0. So I want to remove the first 1 in the byte and make it a 0

Comment: @paddy can you elaborate?

Comment: Uhh, sure.  These are common bitwise operations.  `~` is the bitwise-not and `&` is bitwise-and.  Write it on paper and do it.  You'll see.